# Firebase Cloud Function deployment error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with **Firebase cloud functions** and facing errors while deploying the functions. There are different errors every time. Right now, it's `"Server Error: Unexpected Response. Please try again"`. Whereas, Sometimes it's `"Server Error. socket hang up"`

I checked `firebase-debug.log` file, which states that service is not available, whereas, as per [Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/), it's working fine

**Another Issue with Naming Convention:**

Apart from this, i'm facing issues in deployment when i change the function name from `helloWorld` to something else. It's quite strange as i've total three functions. Two of them are working fine, whereas, when i change the name of helloWorld to something like `generateWeeklyReport`, `newThreadsReport`, `weeklyReport` it fails every time.

I'm using Spark plan of Firebase and right now the names of functions in my index.js file are: `helloWorld, quickChatUserReport, activeThreadsReport`. Is there any naming convention, or is there any limitation on the number of functions in this plan? I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Please guide.

**Side Note**: I read that Kaspersky Endpoint security blocks callbacks resulting in deployment failure. I turned off the protection while deploying function + I'm using node version 9.5.0

Comment: Please contact Firebase support if you have deployment errors without helpful error messages.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: I had to disable Kaspersky anti-virus while deploying the Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue in my case was that I updated `node version` after installing firebase tools. This is the thing which caused the problem and I was not even able to run the functions on my localhost.

I had to uninstall `firebase tools` completely from my machine, remove the `node_modules` folder from my project and then **reinstall** both. It worked.

Commands I used are:

```
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Then I tested my functions as:

```
firebase deploy --only functions --debug  //deployment on cloud
firebase serve --only functions --debug   //testing on localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the --debug flag to your deploy command can provide some additional details

```
firebase deploy --debug --only functions
```

It looks like there have been some intermittent service disruptions with cloud functions over the past week, and I wouldn't be surprised if that is what you are experiencing currently, though the Firebase team isn't [reporting](https://status.firebase.google.com/) any outages currently.

My attempted deploy just now failed with the following error:

```
[2018-03-08T16:55:56.923Z] Error: Firebase.authWithCustomToken failed: First argument must be a valid credential (a string).
```

However, when I confirm I'm authenticated via "firebase login" I receive:

```
Already logged in as xxx@gmail.com
```

I've had this happen on and off over the past few days and it doesn't seem to be related to anything specific in my code or setup.

UPDATE: My deploys just started working again

Comment: Same is the case with me. My code just deployed successfully. Although it's bit annoying... Hopefully, Firebase will fix the issues soon

Comment: and now it's failing again -_-